# Stick div to top on scroll, unstick when scrolling back

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I want to stick a div to top at scroll, unstick it when scrolling back. i know theres a million answers on this, I have tried every example i can find but no-one seems to work for me. I would prefer Vanilla Js too.

Html:

```
<div class="menubar" id="menubar"></div>
```

css:

```
#menubar {
 height: 150px;
 padding-left: 4px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99999999;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: top;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 43px solid #2081c1;
 margin-left: -50%;
 width: 100%t;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: stick on scrolling down , unstick when user is scrolling up???

Comment: take a look http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/js/detecting-scroll-position/